# How to make the picture transit to the left automatically when the screen appeared?

Tags: swiftui

Here's my code:

```
struct StarView: View {
    @State var show = true
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if show {
                Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "star.png")!)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                    .transition(.slide)
                    .onAppear {
                        withAnimation(.spring()) {
                            self.show.toggle()
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. Can the image be moved to the left instead the right?
2. How to prevent the image from disappearing after moving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes the slide come in from the left and I just added a self.show = true below the withAnimation part to prevent it from being hidden.
You can then play around with where to put the self.show = true and make changes to the animation to get different results, if that's what you want. But this code solves the two things you mentioned.

```
struct StarView: View {
    @State var show = true
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if show {
                Image(uiImage: UIImage(named "star.png")!)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
                    .onAppear {
                        withAnimation(.spring()) {
                            self.show.toggle()
                        }
                        self.show = true
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to make it move to the left, return to the starting point, and move to the right repeatedly? I have tried to add `.animation(Animation.linear.speed(0.1))`, it worked, but it showed **'animation' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: Use withAnimation or animation(_:value:) instead.**

Comment: You just need to add value like this .animation(.linear(duration: 0.3), value: 0) but please ask a new question in the future when there is a new issue.